# How to use <%=TagName%> in React-Redux Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have tags in json file and i want to load that static tag from there,because i'm maintained language specific json files for tags .

In react components not accepting the tags like  <%=TagName%> this.. how can i do that..thanks in advance

```
import React from 'react';

    const HomePage = () => {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>React Slingshot</h1>
          Here i want to Show my Tag Name like <%=TagName%> how can i show here...
        </div>
      );
    };

    export default HomePage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&gt;` and `&lt;` which are > and < encoded character in html.

Answer (score 0):

I would use ES6 template strings for it

at the beginning u will pass assign tagname like: `const tagname = 'p'` and then your render method would be something like:

```
    <div>
      <h1>React Slingshot</h1>
        Here i want to Show my Tag Name like { `<${tagname}>`} how can i show here...
    </div>
```

Comment: i want to get that tagname const from local json file which is language specific constant tag name .. ihave multiple json files in my folder based on language section i want to load that json and put the tag in my DIV leve to show that , how can i do that in this example any suggestions thank you :)

Comment: you retrieve them using ajax, then u loop the result over the html above and for every entry set the tagname before